# WPF: how to bind ComboBox ItemsSource in code?

Tags: wpf, binding, itemssource

I need to convert this following XAML into code-behind:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Level}" ItemsSource="{Binding Levels}" />
```

However, this code doesn't compile:

```
new ComboBox() { SelectedItem = new Binding("Level"), ItemsSource = new Binding("Levels") }
```

The error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)". How do I cast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ComboBox cbo=new ComboBox();
cbo.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty,new Binding("Level"){ /* set properties here*/});
cbo.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty,new Binding("Levels"));
....
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You must mean "ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty" instead of "ComboBox.ItemsProperty" (because I can't find such one), right? Otherwise, it works fine. But can you explain why? How to cast as asked in the error message? I need to make that (casting) work because I also need to set ItemsSource binding for DataGridComboBoxColumn which doesn't have SetBinding method.

Comment: @miliu: I have corrected the error - thanks. Use the ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty for the DataGridComboBoxColumn. However there is a big caveat: DataGridComboBoxColumn takes not part of the visual tree and therefore, definining Bindings is a little bit tricky. Google for "DataGridComboBoxColumn and Binding", then you will probably get a lot of posts concerning this. You can use the following code set a binding for any DependencyProperty: BindingOperations.SetBinding(yourDataGridCbo, dependencyProperty, binding);

Comment: Thanks a million! I couldn't make it work using DataGridComoBoxColumn, but I made it work using DataGridTemplateColumn.