# Binding Combo Box to an array of string (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am trying to bind a combo box to an array in the code behind as the following :

```
private readonly string[] Bindlist ={..}
.
.
.
ComboBox newCombo = new ComboBox();
newCombo.ItemsSource = Bindlist ;
```

but an error is thrown that a cast from string to comboboxitem is not possible.

Any idea how to solve this?

thank you

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF ComboBox binding ItemsSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373643/wpf-combobox-binding-itemssource)

Comment: This uses XAML. I need a solution purely from Code side.

Comment: [Sure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6252898/1997232).

Comment: nobody ever reads exception messages :(

Comment: @vasily.sib I do. Nevertheless, sometimes it is in vain xD

Comment: @ShortCircuit, no, you don't. As it said in the exception on your image (which [is useless](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) btw), you can not convert object of type `string` to an object of type `ComboBoxItem`. So as of your question _"how to solve this?"_ - transform each `string` to `ComboBoxItem` in your code.

Comment: @vasily.sib can you give in (example) how you "transform" a string to a ComboBoxItem. I am curious how one can achieve that.

Comment: @ShortCircuit: Where exactly is the exception thrown in your code? It seems like you are trying to cast a `string` to a `ComboBoxItem` somwhere and this will never work.

Comment: @ShortCircuit StackOverflow is _not_ a write-my-code service, but ok, here you go for this time: `private ComboBoxItem TransformToComboBoxItem(string value) => new ComboBoxItem { Content = value };`

Comment: @vasily.sib you seem a bit edgy if you ask me. Nobody forced you to. this is actually not a "one-page code" it is just a one line. But I will be polite and thank you for your much-appreciated contribution. Back to your solution, it is actually for one string not for an array so it is not relevant to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but that works without problem;

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private readonly string[] Bindlist = { "str1", "str2" };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ComboBox box = new ComboBox();
        box.ItemsSource = Bindlist;

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, will try it again and see why i get the error.